# Undefined local variable in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and am having a bit of trouble. I am getting an

```
undefined local variable or method `answer'
```

error in my _answer.html.erb partial.

Here is my answers_controller.rb:

```
  class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


 def index
   @question = Question.find params[:question_id]
   @question.answers
 end


  def show
  end


 def new
    @question = Question.find params[:question_id]
 end


 def edit
 end


  def create
   @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
   @answer = @question.answers.create(answer_params)

   respond_to do |format|
    if @answer.save
     format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @answer }
   else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end


   def update
     respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.update(answer_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @answer, notice: 'Answer was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
   else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end


  def destroy
    @answer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to answers_url }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
 end
```

and my _answer.html.erb file:

```
  <%=div_for(answer) do %>
  <div class="questioncontainer">
   <p> 
  <%= answer.body %>
   </p>
   </div>
   <% end %>
```

If it matters, my resources :answers is nested in resources :questions.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Where/how do you render the answer?

Comment: Which action gives the error? What does :set_answer do?

Comment: @DaveNewton I render it in my _question.html.erb file with <%= render "answers/answer" %>

Comment: The first line gives me the error but if i delete it then the <%= @answer.body %> line gives an error. Not sure what you mean by :set_answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `div_for(@answer)` instead of `answer`. When you're communicating between controllers and views, you always do so with `@variables`. Maybe you should take some time and read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Awesome, this works except now when i try and enter an answer the second line of def create in the answers_controller gives me an undefined method `answers' error.

Comment: This happens because you are mistakenly creating Answer as `question.answers.create(answer_params)`. I imagine you should do it by `Answer.create(params[:user_id], params[:answer_body])` or something like that, but I can't actually know without seeing your Answer's model. But in all honesty, you really have some major concepts to learn about RoR. I suggest you to really dig on some books or classes before you start creating a RoR application. You should try: [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) , it's made for beginners and should help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks so much! I definitely will try out Rails for zombies.